# Apps Script - e.parameter

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a script that checks a lot of checkboxes in google apps script, all named ij, where j is a number from 0 to 73
In the callback is there any way of having e.parameter.ij like I have done below

```
  for (var j = 0; j <= 73; j++) {
 var ij = 'i'+j


 if(e.parameter.ij == 'true' ){
 cell = sheet.getRange(j, column).setValue(awardValue);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
for (var j = 0; j <= 73; j++) {
  var ij = 'i' + j;
  if (e.parameter[ij] == 'true') 
    cell = sheet.getRange(j, column).setValue(awardValue);
 }
```

please check if you have included the checkboxes as callback elements in your server handler